# Eclipse plugin dev: make bundle to explode inside `plugins` folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, nodeclipse

There is old Eclipse Image Viewer plugin https://github.com/persal/quickimage
that I want to update.

After adding maven/tycho build and building against Kepler.

It works in new Eclipse instance (project -> run as Eclipse application),
but when installing here is an issue [#6](https://github.com/persal/quickimage/issues/6)

> org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: i/o error (java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\D:\Progs\Eclipses\eclipse-standard-luna-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\nu.psnet.quickimage.plugin_1.1.0.201503030326.jar!\icons\previous.gif (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.))
>
> 文件名、目录名或卷标语法不正确

Looking at the code there is line

> iconsdir = FileLocator.resolve(QuickImagePlugin.getDefault().getBundle().getEntry("/")).getFile() + "icons" + File.separator;

that gets path like that.

The problem is that should work if the bungle jar becomes folder like `nu.psnet.quickimage_1.0.3.2`

UPDATE: As IDE using Luna 4.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the source of the plugin you can change

```java
iconsdir = FileLocator.resolve(QuickImagePlugin.getDefault().getBundle().getEntry("/")).getFile() + "icons" + File.separator;
```

to something like:

```java
URL dir = FileLocator.find(QuickImagePlugin.getDefault().getBundle(),
                           new Path("icons"), null);

dir = FileLocator.toFileURL(dir);

String iconsdir = dir.getPath() + File.separator;
```

This should work even when the plugin is packaged in a jar.

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled by a flag in feature.xml where the plugin is included.

```
<plugin id="..." unpack="true"/>
```

Comment: I have added line unpack="true" inside feature.xml https://github.com/Nodeclipse/quickimage/blob/master/quickimage-feature/feature.xml#L33-37
But after rebuild and re-installing there is still only single `nu.psnet.quickimage.plugin_1.1.0.201503030412.jar`

Comment: Are you certain that your feature is being picked up by your build process? Take a look at the feature jar in your built repository and see if the contained feature.xml file matches it.

Comment: I have played long with eclipse-standard-luna-R-win32-x86_64 and sts-3.6.0.RELEASE they both do not make plugin unpacked, but just put nu.psnet.quickimage.plugin_1.1.0.201503030701.jar into plugins.